# Python - PHP отличия побитового сдвига

Tags: php, python

Пожалуйста поясните в чем косяк, переписываю одну функцию с php на python.
Осуществляется такой сдвиг:

```
result = 64258459214166963 << 11
```

В результате получаю:

```
PHP
result = 2474115954647078912.

Python
result = 131601324470613940224.
```

Где мой косяк?

**Понял по поводу некоректного поведения PHP, собственно выплывает вопрос, можно ли повторить такое же некоректное поведение в Python?**

Comment: В варианте у пайтона 19 чисел в PHP же 20.

Comment: Поясните, не пойму о чем вы.

Comment: не можете вы такой результат в Питоне получить. Копируйте точно/как есть/один в один.

Comment: В PHP случается переполнение 64-битного целого числа, и он начинает выдавать мусор. Правильный результат именно в Python

Comment: Понял по поводу некоректного поведения PHP, собственно выплывает вопрос, можно ли повторить такое же некоректное поведение в Python?

Comment: @AlekseyPanchenko, (64258459214166963 << 11) % 2\*\*64 или (64258459214166963 << 11) & (2**64 - 1)

Comment: @AlekseyPanchenko, ещё так: import ctypes a = ctypes.c_longlong(64258459214166963 << 11)  a = a.value

Comment: @КириллМалышев это нормально будет работать с отрицательными числами? (лень самому проверять)

Comment: @andreymal, первые два варианта приводятся к беззнаковым, с ctypes можно выбрать c_longlong или c_ulonglong

Comment: Вы осознаёте, что `131601324470613940224. != 131601324470613940224` в Питоне?

Comment: @jfs вы осознаёте, что человек просто мог дописать точку при написании вопроса?

Comment: @andreymal прочтите первый мой комментарий. К чему спрашивать? Вы так и хотите ложную информацию в вопросе оставить? Чтобы в заблуждение людей вводить?

Comment: @jfs в истории правок есть нормальный пример, который автор почему-то удалил

Comment: @andreymal я думаю, что это просто ошибка форматирования кода со стороны автора (код показан как код, но знаки препинания из обычного текста остались). Так как автор вероятно не видит разницы, то исправление этого в категории "противоречит намерению автора" (то есть подобную правку только сам автор может сделать).